# Why doesn't memcpy work when copying a char array into a struct?

Tags: c++, file-io, struct, memcpy, id3

```
#define buffer 128    

int main(){
  char buf[buffer]="";

  ifstream infile("/home/kevin/Music/test.mp3",ios::binary);
  infile.seekg(-buffer,ios::end);
  if(!infile || !infile.read(buf,buffer)){
      cout<<"fail!"<<endl;
  }
  ID3v1 id3;
  cout<<sizeof(id3)<<endl;
  memcpy(&id3,buf,128);
  cout<<id3.header<<endl;
}


struct ID3v1{
  char header[3];
  char title[30];
  char artist[30];
  char album[30];
  char year[4];
  char comment[28];
  bool zerobyte;
  bool track;
  bool genre;

};
```

When I do the memcpy, it seems to be pushing too much data into the header field. Do I need to go through each of the structs members and copy the data in? I'm also using c++, but this seems more of a "C" strategy. Is there a better way for c++?

Comment: You can't 'push more data' into a char[3], you can only read too much because it isn't zero-terminated.

Comment: Your `ID3v1.header` is most likely not null-terminated. You are printing everything until `\0`.

Comment: I strongly suggest you don't name your buffer and buffer size `buf` and `buffer`. Why not name one `buf` and the other `bufSize`? Or `buffer` and `bufferSize`? This is confusing! Additionally, if all you want to copy is the ID3 tag and its size is `128`, then replace all `128` by a constant with a meaningful name, for example `ID3TAG_SIZE` or whatever.

Comment: To add onto 111111, are you sure that the data you are getting in that c-string is what you want?

Comment: Yea I think thats it then, because the data is correct for the rest of the input. I was making sure I was using memcpy correctly, I never used it before, but the tag data isn't zero-terminated.

Comment: @hochi Yea i was going to rename it, just some code thrown together for now without thought, thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in all the comments (you are missing the '\0' character, or when printing C-Strings the operator<< is expecting the sequence of characters to be '\0' terminated).

Try:

```
std::cout << std::string(id3.header, id3.header+3) << std::endl;
```

This will print the three characters in the header field.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely in that the `memcpy` does what it does.

It copies the 128bytes into your structure.

Then you try to print out the header. It prints the 1st character, 2nd, 3rd.. and continues to print until it finds the `'\0'` (string termination character).

Basically, when printing things out, copy the header to another char array and append the termination character (or copy to an c++ string).

Answer (score 0):

other problems you may encounter when using memcpy:

- your struct elements may be align to word boundaries by the compiler.
  most compilers have some pragma or commandline switch to specify the alignment to use.
- some cpu's require shorts or longs to be stored on word boundaries, in that case modifying the alignment will not help you, as you will not be able to read from the unaligned addresses.
- if you copy integers larger than char ( like short, or long ) you have to make sure to correct the byte order depending on your cpu architecture.